# vueJs data-table alternative jquery data-table

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

I created a crud system with vueJs and laravel. Now I want to use a data-table like jquery data-table for my vueJs app with laravel blade file. Suggest a best vue-table which easy to implement. Thank you.

Comment: you can use [bootstrap-vue table](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table)

Comment: @Mostakim Billah.....can i use it in blade file?

Comment: You have to use it as a vue component

Comment: Is there any way to use a component in blade file?

Comment: definitely you can use vue component in blade file. Please follow [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/frontend#writing-vue-components)

Comment: Tnx for your kind information.

Comment: @MostakimBillah the link is https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-table-vue